# Option configuration-cache doesn't accept value 'true'. Possible values are [OFF, ON, WARN]

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to build an Android application in Android studio. However, getting the error as `Option configuration-cache doesn't accept value 'true'. Possible values are [OFF, ON, WARN]`. Checked all the gradle files on where I can update this configuration-cache option. But no luck. I tried to run the gradle task with --stacktrace. and below is the output. Where Can I update this option? Kindly help. Thanks!

Android Gradle plugin version : 4.1.2
Gradle version : 6.5

Stack trace :

```
* Exception is:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Option configuration-cache doesn't accept value 'true'. Possible values are [OFF, ON, WARN]
        at org.gradle.internal.buildoption.EnumBuildOption.getValue(EnumBuildOption.java:87)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildoption.EnumBuildOption.applyTo(EnumBuildOption.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildoption.EnumBuildOption.applyFromProperty(EnumBuildOption.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.converter.PropertiesToStartParameterConverter.convert(PropertiesToStartParameterConverter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ParametersConverter.convert(ParametersConverter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ParametersConverter.convert(ParametersConverter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.BuildActionsFactory.createAction(BuildActionsFactory.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.createAction(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:299)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:289)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:266)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:92)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:259)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:50)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:31)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds silly, but just changed the configuration-config option as suggested by the error in `user/.gradle/gradle.properties`, and project compiled succcessfully. But other android studio projects compile successfully with value `true`. Maybe this has to do something with the gradle version.